# How to make python 3.6 use visual studio 2017 instead of 2015?

Tags: python, python-3.x, msbuild, python-3.6

I have Python 3.6 and Visual Studio 2017, not 2015 and I want to make pip3.6 build libraries use VS2017 instead of VS2015.

PS: When installing VS2017, I chose VS2015 Update 3 build tools, but unfortunately pip3.6 does NOT find it. So I decided to switch to VS2017 build tools. I used VS2017 command prompt and issued `pip install somelibrary` and it worked, but I want to be able to do this in every command prompt window like the time I had VS2015.

Answer (score 0):

VS 2017 Build Tools does not set up global environment variables as 2015 does. Set this environment variable

```
VS150COMNTOOLS
```

to (64-bit Windows)

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\Common7\Tools\
```

or (32-bit Windows)

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\Common7\Tools\
```

and you should be able to pip install correctly as with VS 2015.